# Adding commas to a number from a list

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a list that contains tuples inside. for example:

```
[('x', 'y', 'z', '1111111'), ('a', 'b', 'c', '2222222')]
```

and so on...

Basically, I just want the numbers from the tuples to be displayed in a format like this: `1,111,111` or `2,222,222`

Here is the code I used so far: `"{0[3]:7}".format(mylist)`
If I was to add a comma in to separate the number into the right format, I get an error saying saying it `Cannot specify ',' with 's'.`

The code that produces the error:

```
"{0[3]:,}".format(mylist)
```

I get that s means string, but do I have to convert the numbers from the list to an int/float beforehand?

Comment: Well, yeah. It is after all [a numeric formatting instruction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). You don't have any numbers now, you have strings.

Comment: @usr2564301 Yeah thanks. Just changed number into an int.

Comment: You want me to expand this into a full answer? It would merely reiterate the above comment, possibly with some working code added. If I don't, some reputation hunter *will* do. You could also delete this question before it's going to attract downvotes for "lack of research" or "too broad" or "unclear" (which, mind you, will count against you even when it's deleted).